# I am fetching rss feeds which has some images that are from flickr. How to fetch those images?

Tags: android

You can refer to the feeds at https://letstalkbitcoin.com/rss/feed/blog

They have images but from www.flickr.com

Comment: what have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: I have fetched all the data but while fetching the images they didn't provide img url instead they provided flickr.com link which has more than one image

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glider](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to fetch the images. Both libraries have extensive documentation and take care of optimizations like caching, processing images, etc.

Comment: I have fetched all the data but while fetching the images they didn't provide img url instead they provided flickr.com link which has more than one image

Comment: Well, in that case, you can use something like JSoup to parse the HTML contents of the flick page and extract all images that you need.